# PHP Check if process is running (Linux)

Tags: php, linux, exec

I am trying to figure out if a gameserver is running. I found a lot of dirty methods so I wanted to make it basically easy by calling a PHP script which checks if a process is running. Well what I was trying was:

```
<?php
exec("bin_unix/linux_server", $output, $return);
if ($return == 0) {
    echo "Ok, process is running\n";
} else {
    echo "Process is not running\n";
}
```

but its not working (since I am sure the process is running).. its not a "real" process don't blame me I am not an linux expert.

So what I do to run this server is the following command:

```
cd /path/to/server/ && nohup bin_unix/linux_server &
```

I guess the `bin_unix/linux_server` in the `exec();` is wrong, but its the only static information I get with `ps aux`.

The process_id will change often so I am not sure what to type there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pidof` command, look here: [pidof command](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_pidof.htm)